# How to use OASIS UBL 2.1 for product modelling

Tags: xsd, schema, standards, oasis

We are developing a system that stores product information. We want to use a standard as the schema for our data and [OASIS Universal Business Language standard 2.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1.html) seems to be reasonable.

The problem is that it is not really clear how to model your products into this schema. Are there any examples available on how to use this standard for a product model?

For example, the `ItemType` seems to be suitable for a product with it's information - but how can the variants of a product be depicted?

Also, are there any other standard that are more comprehensible/are more suitable for this use-case?